# "And twelve points goes to...." Or go?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

In the final concert of [Eurovision Song Contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest), when the scores are announced, representatives from many countries say "eight/ten/twelve points ***goes*** to...".  This sounds completely wrong to me, "points" is plural after all. But since many say so I thought that maybe this is a standard way of announcing the results. Maybe it's just shortened "the result of twelve points goes to". I can't believe that so many people say it wrong for so many years.

Is it appropriate to use singular announcing the scores this way or is it a bad English?

Update: I watched the [jury votes of 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=398C_2-t4TY) now and he majority seem to say "twelve point go to...". Maybe it was just my selective perception about "almost everyone" so I edited the question but it still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Twelve points goes to" is not necessarily incorrect, if the speaker is thinking of the points as constituting **one object**.

For example,

"**One hundred dollars** goes to Contestant #1."

is very natural (we frequently think of "one hundred dollars" as a single object, and it might even be a single 100-dollar bill). But

"**Three bicycles** goes to Contestant #1."

sounds very unnatural (since we would almost never think of three bicycles as constituting one object).

"**Twelve points** goes to Contestant #1."

is in the middle: it might not be very common, but it is not totally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the good question. I've just checked the Eurovision voting videos on YouTube. They all say *12 points **go** to...*. Here is the link - 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfI4k5A1aLE

Find minute 22:22 to hear the result of the Irish vote then. I believe we can trust the Irish even more than the others because Ireland is an English-speaking country. However, all of the reporters must be worth trusting for their English is good, they seem to be professional enough and they all repeat the same form of the verb.

Comment: May 2015 was an exceptional year ) In the link on my question (votes fo 2016) not a neglectable part says "goes". F.e. Bosnia and Herzegovina (5:40). And in [2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldvY7sQTweQ) some say "goes" too.

Comment: It means only one thing - both ways are right. If they say "12 points go", they consider the subject to be a plural noun phrase. If they say "12 points goes", "12 points" is considered to be single unit, which, therefore, "goes". As for the exceptional year, how can it be? I have serious doubts about all those people discussing which form of the verb to use at some particular contest. So just take it as "I need another 5 minutes" or something like that. There times when a plural noun is followed by "Vs" and it's one of them.